# how to fetch data from mysql to dropdown(form) by using reactjs and node js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I am new developer ReactJS, I develop a form with ReactJS on the Front End, NodeJS on Back End and MySQL about the database.I want to display the data in dropdown and in this there are two dropdowns based on selection of 1st dropdown the 2nd dropdown should display the data from mysql

> ```
>   register.js
> ```

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react' 
   import { register } from './UserFunctions'

    class Register extends Component { constructor() { super() this.state = { business_name: '', 
   first_name: '', last_name: '', email: '', phone_number: '', cell_number: '', fax_number: '', 
   address1:'', 
    address2:'', city:'', state:'', country:'', password: '', errors: {} }

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
   }


onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const newUser = {
        business_name: this.state.business_name,
        first_name: this.state.first_name,
        last_name: this.state.last_name,
        email: this.state.email,
        phone_number: this.state.phone_number,
        cell_number: this.state.cell_number,
        fax_number: this.state.fax_number,
        address1: this.state.address1,
        address2: this.state.address2,
        city: this.state.city,
        state: this.state.state,
        zipcode: this.state.zipcode,
        country: this.state.country,
        password: this.state.password
    }

    register(newUser).then(res => {
        this.props.history.push(`/login`)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6 mt-5 mx-auto">
                    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <h1 className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Register</h1>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="name">Business name</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="business_name"
                                placeholder="Enter your business name"
                                value={this.state.business_name}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">theraputic area</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">i need to diplay 
     data here
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">disease</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
                                <option>1</option>
                                <option>2</option>
                                <option>3</option>
                                <option>4</option>
                                <option>5</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>


                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="name">First name</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="first_name"
                                placeholder="Enter your first name"
                                value={this.state.first_name}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="name">Last name</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="last_name"
                                placeholder="Enter your last name"
                                value={this.state.last_name}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="email">Email address</label>
                            <input
                                type="email"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="email"
                                placeholder="Enter email"
                                value={this.state.email}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="phone">Phone number</label>
                            <input
                                type="number"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="phone_number"
                                placeholder="Enter phone number"
                                value={this.state.phone_number}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="phone">Cell number</label>
                            <input
                                type="number"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="cell_number"
                                placeholder="Enter cell number"
                                value={this.state.cell_number}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="phone">Fax number</label>
                            <input
                                type="number"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="fax_number"
                                placeholder="Enter phone number"
                                value={this.state.fax_number}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="add1">Address1</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="address1"
                                placeholder=""
                                value={this.state.address1}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </div>



                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="add2">Address2</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="address2"
                                placeholder=""
                                value={this.state.address2}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </div>



                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="cit">City</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="city"
                                placeholder=""
                                value={this.state.city}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="sta">State</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="state"
                                placeholder=""
                                value={this.state.state}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </div>


                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="sta">Zipcode</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="zipcode"
                                placeholder=""
                                value={this.state.zipcode}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect3">Country</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect3" value= 
        {this.state.country} onChange={this.onChange}>
                                <option>1</option>
                                <option>2</option>
                                <option>3</option>
                                <option>4</option>
                                <option>5</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                            <input
                                type="password"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="password"
                                placeholder="Password"
                                value={this.state.password}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
                        >
                            Register!
          </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
   }
  }
   export default Register
```

> (routes)Users.js routing

```
   const express = require('express') const users = express.Router() const cors = 
   require('cors') const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken') const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

  const User = require('../models/User')
   users.use(cors())

 process.env.SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

  users.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  const today = new Date()
   const userData = {
    business_name: req.body.business_name,
    first_name: req.body.first_name,
    last_name: req.body.last_name,
    email: req.body.email,
    phone_number: req.body.phone_number,
    cell_number: req.body.cell_number,
    fax_number: req.body.fax_number,
    address1: req.body.address1,
    address2: req.body.address2,
    city: req.body.city,
    state: req.body.state,
    zipcode: req.body.zipcode,
    country: req.body.country,
    password: req.body.password,
    created: today
  }

   User.findOne({
    where: {
        email: req.body.email
    }
   })
    //TODO bcrypt
    .then(user => {
        if (!user) {
            bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
                userData.password = hash
                User.create(userData)
                    .then(user => {
                        res.json({ status: user.email + 'Registered!' })
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        res.send('error: ' + err)
                    })
            })
        } else {
            res.json({ error: 'User already exists' })
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.send('error: ' + err)
    })
  })

   users.post('/login', (req, res) => { User.findOne({ where: { email: req.body.email } }) .then(user => 
  { 
   if (user) { if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) { let token = 
   jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY, { expiresIn: 1440 }) res.send(token) } } else { 
   res.status(400).json({ error: 'User does not exist' }) } }) .catch(err => { res.status(400).json({ 
   error: 
    err }) }) })

   users.get('/profile', (req, res) => { var decoded = jwt.verify(req.headers['authorization'], 
    process.env.SECRET_KEY)

    User.findOne({
    where: {
        id: decoded.id
    }
    })
    .then(user => {
        if (user) {
            res.json(user)
        } else {
            res.send('User does not exist')
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.send('error: ' + err)
    })
    })

    module.exports = users

    users.get('/register',(req,res) => { var Code = req.query.Code;
    how to call


})
```

> model(user.js)schema file

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../database/db.js')

module.exports = db.sequelize.define(
    'user',
    {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        business_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        first_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        last_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        phone_number: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        cell_number: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        fax_number: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        address1: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        address2: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        city: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        state: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        zipcode: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        country: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        created: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: false
    }
)
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I want to display the data in dropdown and in this there are two dropdowns based on selection of 1st dropdown the 2nd dropdown should display the data from mysql